# Angular2 ckeditor edit config

Tags: angular, configuration, ckeditor

This is how CKEditor document says to configure the editor http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_toolbarconcepts-section-toolbar-groups-configuration

i'm using like this in html

```
<ckeditor
  [(ngModel)]="ckeditorContent"
  [config]="{toolbar : 'Basic', uiColor: '#FFFFFF'}"
  (change)="onChange($event)"
  (ready)="onReady($event)"
  (focus)="onFocus($event)"
  (blur)="onBlur($event)"
  debounce="1000"
  >
</ckeditor>
```

So how to give this configuration to my CKEditor in angular2???

Comment: https://github.com/chymz/ng2-ckeditor. You should pass the config object in the config Input

Comment: ok if i pass the config through config input it works thank you

Comment: This is my answer, it's not fair :)

Comment: ok then submit as a answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/chymz/ng2-ckeditor) you should pass **config** object as Input:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'sample',
  template: `
  <ckeditor
    [config]="config">
  </ckeditor>
  `
})
export class Sample{
  constructor(){
    this.config = {uiColor: '#99000'};
  }
}
```

Comment: how can i remove unnecessary icon from CKeditor using **config**?

Comment: @Chaudhary Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the config object through the config input

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-ckeditor

Generally, we can use below config value to remove toolbar in angular and react js

```
this.ckeConfig = {
      allowedContent: false,
      forcePasteAsPlainText: true,
      removePlugins: 'horizontalrule,tabletools,specialchar,about,list,others',
      removeButtons: 'Save,NewPage,Preview,Print,Templates,Replace,SelectAll,Form,Checkbox,Radio,TextField,Textarea,Find,Select,Button,ImageButton,HiddenField,JustifyLeft,JustifyCenter,JustifyRight,JustifyBlock,CopyFormatting,CreateDiv,BidiLtr,BidiRtl,Language,Flash,Smiley,PageBreak,Iframe,Font,FontSize,TextColor,BGColor,ShowBlocks,Cut,Copy,Paste,Table,Image,Format,Source,Maximize,Styles,Anchor,SpecialChar,PasteFromWord,PasteText,Scayt,Undo,Redo,Strike,RemoveFormat,Indent,Outdent,Blockquote,Underline'
    };
```